# objective-c fill up color in specific area and only when touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors

I have tried and searched a lot but have not find a solutions.

I have f.e this picture as a .png [1]: http://imm.io/1f3DY

If the user touches f.e. in the area 1

I want to fill up this area with color f.e. blue.

Is there any way to find out/create these areas in code and fill it up with colors?

I have convert my .png to .svg and created some bezierpathes. Stored the bezierpathes in an array and add a gesturerecognizer. This works fine. Got the right path which I have touched. Can change the color of the path. But only the black lines. I want to fill up the space between f.e. path1 and path 2. How can I do this?

```
       //The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

    location.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - location.y;
    for(int i = 0; i< bezierPathes.count; i++)
    {
          //if([b containsPoint:location])

        UIBezierPath* b = bezierPathes[i];
        if([[self tapTargetForPath:b] containsPoint:location])
        {
            [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
            [b fill];
            [testView setNeedsDisplay];

        }

    }
}

// this method will let you easily select a bezier path ( 15 px up and down of a path drawing)
- (UIBezierPath *)tapTargetForPath:(UIBezierPath *)path
{
    if (path == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    CGPathRef tapTargetPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path.CGPath, NULL, fmaxf(35.0f, path.lineWidth), path.lineCapStyle, path.lineJoinStyle, path.miterLimit);
    if (tapTargetPath == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIBezierPath *tapTarget = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:tapTargetPath];
    CGPathRelease(tapTargetPath);
    return tapTarget;
}
```

Comment: If you have just an image (jpg, png, whatever) you will have to us an edge detection algorithm since you can't have the area that you want to fill from the image. Or you can define some coordinates for every shape you want to fill and then use core graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with Flood Fill algorithm.

Hear is the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill